# Iwahori action on the $p$-ordinary line of a principal series representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}\DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}\newcommand\Iw{\mathrm{Iw}}\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}$Let $F$ be a $p$-adic local field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\GL_n(F)$ be the general linear group with diagonal torus $T_n(F)$, upper triangular Borel $B_n(F)$ and Weyl group $W(\GL_n, T_n)$.

Let $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n: F^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be $n$ quasicharacters of $F$. We introduce a modified character
$$
\lambda^{\natural}: T_n(F) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}, \quad \diag[t_1, \dotsc, t_n] \mapsto \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lvert t_i\rvert^{n-i} \lambda_i(t_i)
$$
and define an *algebraically induced principal series representation* $I_{B_n}^{\GL_n}(\lambda) := \Ind_{B_n(F)}^{\GL_n(F)}(\lambda^{\natural})$.

**Setup**: Let $\pi$ be a generic irreducible admissible representation of $\GL_n(F)$ with Whittaker model $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)$ with respect to a generic character $\psi$ of $U_n(F)$ trivial on $U_n(\mathcal{O}_F)$. We assume that $\pi$ occurs as a subquotient of $I_{B_n}^{\GL_n}(\lambda)$ such that $\lambda^{w}$ for $w \in W(\GL_n, T_n)$ are pairwise distinct.

**Hecke story**: Consider

- *Iwahori subgroups*: For any $\alpha \geq \beta \geq 0$, we write $\Iw_{\beta, \alpha}$ for the subgroup of matrices in $\GL_n(\mathcal{O}_F)$ that become upper triangular modulo $\varpi^{\alpha}$, and which lies in $U_n(\mathcal{O}_F/\varpi^{\beta})$ when reduced modulo $\varpi^{\beta}$. We set $\Iw_{\alpha} = \Iw_{0, \alpha}$.
- Define $$\Delta_{F} := T_n(\mathcal{O}_F^{\times}) \cdot  \{\varpi^{e}:=\diag[\varpi^{e_1}, \dotsc, \varpi^{e_n}]: e_1 \geq e_2 \geq \cdots \geq e_n \geq 0 \} \subset T_n(F).$$

Then the Iwahori–Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}(\beta,\alpha)$ is defined as the double coset algebra $\mathcal{H}(\Iw_{\beta, \alpha}, \Iw_{\beta, \alpha} \Delta_{F}\Iw_{\beta, \alpha})$. For $1 \leq \nu \leq n$, we write $\omega_\nu$ for the $\nu$-th fundamental weight with $\nu$ leading $1$'s and $n-\nu$ tailing $0$'s, i.e. $\omega_\nu = (\underbrace{1, \dotsc, 1}_\nu, \underbrace{0, \dotsc, 0}_{n - \nu})$, we define the **Hecke operator** $V_{\nu} := \Iw_{\beta, \alpha} \varpi^{\omega_{\nu}} \Iw_{\beta, \alpha}$.

**Ordinary line**: Let $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)_{\ord}$ be the subspace of $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)^{U_n(\mathcal{O}_F)}$ consisting of simultaneous $V_{\nu}$-eigenvector $W$ for $1 \leq \nu < n$ with nonzero eigenvalues (union with $0$). Then Proposition 1.3 of [arXiv 1708.02616](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02616) says that $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)_{\ord}$ is one dimensional. We call it the ordinary line.

**My question is**: how does the Iwahori subgroup $\Iw_{\alpha}$ act on this ordinary line?

To be more precise, one checks that $\Iw_{\alpha}$ acts on $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)^{U_n(\mathcal{O}_F)}$ naturally. Since $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)_{\ord}$ is one dimensional, there exists a character $\vartheta: \mathrm{Iw}_{\alpha} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that
$$
W(gr) = \vartheta(r) W(g), \quad \forall g \in \GL_n(F), r \in \Iw_{\alpha}.
$$
Then **how to describe this character $\vartheta$?**. More concretely, I wonder:

1. **Does $\vartheta$ arise from the subtorus of $\Iw_{\alpha}$?** i.e. do there exist quasicharacters $\theta_1, \dotsc, \theta_n: F^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ of conductors dividing $\varpi^{\alpha}$ such that
   $$
   \vartheta((r_{ij})_{i,j}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta_i(r_{ii})?
   $$
   If so, where can I find a reference or is it easy to prove? Or at least *for sufficiently large $\alpha$*?
2. **What is the relation between the quasicharacters $\lambda_i$ and the "Iwahori type" character $\vartheta$ (or $\theta_1, \dotsc, \theta_n$)**?

---

*My attempts to understand these*: I am trying to see that for some $\alpha \geq \beta \geq 0$, there is a filtration
$$
\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)_{\ord} \subseteq \mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)^{\Iw_{\beta, \alpha}} \subseteq \mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)^{U_n(\mathcal{O}_F)}.\tag{$\star$}\label{464205_star}
$$
Then indeed $\Iw_{\alpha}$ will act via the subtorus, since $\Iw_{\alpha}/\Iw_{\beta, \alpha} \cong T_n(\mathcal{O}_F/\varpi^{\beta})$. But **do such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ really exist**?

*Why I guess like this*? I get the clue from Lemma 4.8 of [arXiv 2306.07039](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.07039), where the author proved that when $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ are all unramified characters, then we can take $\beta = 0$ and $\alpha$ be any positive integer to make the inclusion \eqref{464205_star} come true. But I cannot see how to deal with the general $\lambda^{\natural}$ without the unramified condition.

---

Sorry for such a long and naïve post and thank you all for paying attention. :)

Comment: I changed one occurrence of $\lambda^\sharp$ to $\lambda^\natural$, for consistency. I hope that was OK. \\ If I'm understanding correctly, $\mathrm{Iw}_\alpha$ is the product of its derived subgroup, on which $\vartheta$ vanishes, with $\mathrm{Iw}_\alpha \cap T_n(F)$—so doesn't that mean purely formally that the answer to (1) is "yes"? \\ I am confused by the $W$ that appears in the definition of $\mathcal W(\pi, \psi)_{\operatorname{ord}}$. Of course it's not the Weyl group $W$!  Is it just a shorthand for $\mathcal W(\pi, \psi)$, viewed as a homomorphism on $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you so much for your comments! Yes for $W$ in the definition of $\mathcal{W}(\pi, \psi)_{\mathrm{ord}}$, I mean an arbitrary element in it, being a function $W: \mathrm{GL}_n(F) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. So sorry for the confusions.

Comment: And I guess you are right! Silly of me for the question (1). I shall verify it shortly and thank you for your hints!

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464205/iwahori-action-on-the-p-ordinary-line-of-a-principal-series-representation#comment1205348_464205), the answer to (1) is "yes", at least if the residue field of $F$ is not $\mathbb F_2$, because $\mathrm{Iw}_\alpha$ is the product of its derived subgroup, on which $\vartheta$ is trivial, and $\mathrm{Iw}_\alpha \cap T_n(F)$.

By, and with the notation of, the proof of Proposition 1.3 of [Januszewski - Non-abelian $p$-adic Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions and non-vanishing of central $L$-values](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02616), since $W_{f_0}(1)$ equals $\operatorname{vol}(U_n(\mathcal O_F))$, we have that $W_{f_0}(r)$ equals
$$
\int_{U_n(F)} f_0(w_n u r)\overline\psi(u)\mathrm du =
\int_{U_n(F)} f_0((w_n r w_n^{-1})w_n(r^{-1}u r))\overline\psi(u)\mathrm du =
(\lambda^{\omega w_n})^\natural(w_n r w_n^{-1})\operatorname{vol}(r U(\mathcal O_F)r^{-1}) =
(\lambda^{\omega w_n})^\natural(w_n r w_n^{-1})\operatorname{vol}(U(\mathcal O_F)) =
(\lambda^{\omega w_n})^\natural(w_n r w_n^{-1})W_{f_0}(1)
$$
(since $r$ normalises $U(\mathcal O_F)$), hence that $\vartheta(r)$ equals $(\lambda^{\omega w_n})^\natural(w_n r w_n^{-1})$, for all $r \in \mathrm{Iw}_\alpha \cap T_n(F)$.  This is easy enough to translate into your notation, except that it's not quite an answer to (2), because I don't know what $\omega$ is.  (That is to say, I know how it's defined, in Proposition 1.3(i), but I don't know the actual permutation.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That clears up most of my confusion! Yet when reading the proof of Proposition 1.3 of Januszewski's paper, I wonder: (i) *The Whittaker model of $\pi$ is exactly $\mathrm{Ind}_{U_n(F)}^{\mathrm{GL}_n(F)} \psi$?* Otherwise, the $W_{f_0}$ may not lie in $\mathcal{W}(\pi, \psi)$, so how can $W_{f_0}$ **maps to** the $W^{\prime}$? (ii) By definition, it seems that $\mathrm{Iw}_{\alpha} \cap T_n(F) = T_n(\mathcal{O}_F)$. As you keep using the notation $\mathrm{Iw}_{\alpha} \cap T_n(F)$, I am afraid that I am getting somewhere wrong. Thank you again for your great help!

Comment: and the longest Weyl element $w_n$ seems strange to me. I can only see that once the Jacquet module of $\pi$ admits $(\lambda^{w})^{\natural}$ as a direct summand, then by Frobenius reciprocity, $\pi$ occurs as a submodule of $I(\lambda^{w})$, instead of  $I(\lambda^{ww_n})$? And if so, following your proof, $\vartheta$ would be $(\lambda^{w})^{\natural}$.

Comment: The *Version 5* of Januszewski's paper may make more sense, where it goes like this: "Therefore, by Frobenius reciprocity, $\pi$ occurs as a submodule of $I(\lambda^{w})$, and hence occurs as a **factor module** of $I(\lambda^{ww_n})$". If so, then the question (i) is solved, since $\mathrm{Ind}(\psi)$ **projects to** $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)$.

Comment: @HetongXu, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464205/iwahori-action-on-the-p-ordinary-line-of-a-principal-series-representation/464246#comment1205597_464246), I agree.  I wondered about that, too, but figured that the issue of $W_{f_0}$ being in the image might be addressed elsewhere; it didn't occur to me, despite the language, that the map was just going the wrong way!

Comment: @HetongXu, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464205/iwahori-action-on-the-p-ordinary-line-of-a-principal-series-representation/464246?#comment1205584_464246), I was using the notation $\mathrm{Iw}_\alpha \cap T_n(F)$ only because I took that to be your preferred notation.  It is inded equal to $T_n(\mathcal O_F)$.

Comment: @HetongXu, I encourage you *not* to accept this answer (or, rather, to unaccept it); it is incomplete, because I have not computed $\omega$.  I might get time at some point to see if I can work out what the specific $\omega$ can be, or someone else might, but, either way, I have not fully answered the question.

Comment: Thank you! You have been of great great help!

Comment: And at least when $\pi$ is exactly $I_{B_n}^{\mathrm{GL}_n}(\lambda)$, then it seems that $\omega$ should be the identity permutation.

Comment: @HetongXu, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464205/iwahori-action-on-the-p-ordinary-line-of-a-principal-series-representation/464246#comment1205893_464246), yes, I agree, so if your context allows you to assume that, then that may be all that's needed.